# Наибольшее число палиндром, которое является произведением двух простых пятизначных чисел

Tags: android, циклы, простые-числа

Делал приложение по ТЗ из одной компании. Сделал андроид-аппку, получил результат на эмуляторе, вроде же верный. Но HR просто отписалась, что ответ который выдало мое приложение неверен.
Айчары люди довольно занятые, потому редко кто может указать на ошибку, а навязываться после отказа - дело очень неблагодарное. Но все же хочется хоть для себя выполнить задание до конца.

Из требований было:

> Напишите программу, которая возвращает наибольшее число палиндром, которое
>   является произведением двух простых пятизначных чисел, а также возвращает
>   сами сомножители.
>   Простое число - это натуральное число, которое делится нацело только на 1 и
>   на себя само (2, 3, 5, 7, 11, …)
>   Палиндром – строка, которая читается одинаково в обоих направлениях
>   (например ABBA)

Сам принцип поиска простых чисел мне понятен. Использовать массивы было нецелесообразно потому  решето Эратосфена и аналоги пришлось отбросить - уж очень много памяти сожрало бы создание массива на такое количество значений.

Потому решил использовать циклы для сопоставления и отсеивания.

Вот код моего андроид-приложения:

**MainActivity**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private int maxNum = 99999;
    private int minNum = 10000;

    private int divNumMax = 0;
    private int palind;

    private TextView tv1;
    private TextView tv2;
    private TextView tv3;
    private TextView tv4;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        tv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);

        Button btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btnStart.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        divNumMax = (int) Math.sqrt(maxNum);

        int fPM;
        int sPM;
        boolean isNotPalind;

        fPM = findMaxPrimeNumber(maxNum);
        sPM = findMaxPrimeNumber(fPM - 2);
        isNotPalind = findPalindrome(fPM, sPM);

        while (isNotPalind) {

            if (sPM <= fPM && sPM > minNum) {
                sPM = findMaxPrimeNumber(sPM - 2);
                isNotPalind = findPalindrome(fPM, sPM);

            } else if (sPM <= minNum) {
                fPM = findMaxPrimeNumber(fPM - 2);
                sPM = fPM;
            }

            tv2.setText("1-st primary number: " + fPM);
            tv3.setText("2-nd primary number: " + sPM);
            tv4.setText("1-st * 2-nd = " + palind);

        }
    }


    private int findMaxPrimeNumber(int maxNumPre) {
        int i;
        int j;
        int z;
        int maxNumNew;

        for (i = maxNumPre; i >= minNum; i = i - 2) {

            for (j = 3; j <= divNumMax; j++) {

                z = i % j;

                if (z == 0 && j <= divNumMax) {
                    break;

                } else if (z != 0 && j == divNumMax) {
                    maxNumNew = i;
                    return maxNumNew;

                }
            }

        }
        return 10000;
    }


    private boolean findPalindrome(int firstPrime, int secondPrime) {

        int resultOfMath = firstPrime * secondPrime;

        String ltrResult = Integer.toString(resultOfMath);
        String rtlResult = new StringBuffer(ltrResult).reverse().toString();

        if (ltrResult.equals(rtlResult)) {

            palind = resultOfMath;
            return false;

        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Скриншот полученного результата на эмуляторе:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ломаю голову где ошибся, что упустил. Не прошу делать за меня ТЗ, но не хочу оставлять позади какую-то неразобранную проблемму.

Comment: Придирка была к коду или к результату?

Comment: Дословно: "К сожалению, это неправильный ответ". Но, не думаю что это придирка, так как у человека же ответ перед глазами должен изначально быть, чтобы сверять правильный ответ или нет. Может  она и не знает почему именно ответ не сошелся, но имея ключ - сложно ошибиться. Думаю если бы код не подошел - то тогда бы так и написали.

Comment: `3 * 1 != 1` *(2 символа нужно...)*

Comment: Блин. а ведь точно. не перемножил вручную.

Comment: `Айчары люди довольно занятые` – а ещё они не разбираются в программировании и просто не смогут объяснить вам ошибку.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Та да, это была одна из причин по которой не хотел уточнять у айчара почему ответ неправильный ))

Comment: Вас должен был насторожить уже порядок ответа. Умножение двух чисел порядка `10^5` внезапно дало результат порядка `10^8`?

Comment: Да, я пропустил банальную ручную проверку результата. А глаз на 10-тизначные числа еще ненаметан.

Comment: Я эту задачу решил и отправил на рассмотрение. Но мне отписали, что нужно было решать через решето Эратосфена или решето Аткина.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ваше целое несколько раз завернулось вокруг максимального значения `int` - `2,147,483,647`.

Проверьте:

```
99923 * 87541 = 8 747 359 343
```

*А также:*

На какую цифру должно заканчиваться произведение Ваших двух простых чисел?

Comment: Да, действительно, не проверил вручную результат умножения. Но изначально я не обратил внимание на то что в **int**  не влезет результат умножения!!!  По задаче нет привязки к тому на какую цыфру должно закончиться число. Суть в том чтобы найти максимальный палиндром(число которое читается слева-направо и справа-налево одинаково).

Comment: @V.March Я не говорю, что в задаче есть требование к последней цифре результата. Ваш ответ очевидно неправильный, так как полученые простые числа не могут дать такой результат - их произведение должно заканчиваться на 3.

Comment: я понял о чем Вы. За замечание благодарен, хоть узнал над чем еще работать нужно!

Answer (score 5):

решето работает отлично, ранее искал все простые числа в диапазоне 0- 10 000 000 ушло примерно 15 секунд на планшете. главное правильно написать алгоритм.

возможно я не верно понял ваш алгоритм (прошу исправить меня)

почему второй цикл идет по увеличению параметра, а не от большего к меньшему?

```
for (j = 3; j <= divNumMax; j++) {
```

- есть нюанс: рассмотрим ту же задачу, но в диапазоне 0-15, пока отбросим условие палиндрома (здесь оно  не играет роли).

  `a = 13; b = 2; a*b = 26`

но есть и другие простые числа произведение которых даст значительно больше результат? 11*13 > 26

Comment: Я брал перебор от максимального 5-ти значного числа (99999), так как предположительно простые числа большего значения дадут самый большой результат. Тоеть, нет необходимости перебирать все 90К чисел начиная с 10000, а достаточно найти первое максимальное начиная с 99999, потом найти второе по величине от него, умножить между собой - если палиндром - то ок. еси нет - ищем дальше.

Comment: специально для этого я навел вам пример. то что у вас будет в качестве множителя одно самое больше число НЕ ГАРАНТИРУЕТ максимальное произведение чисел.

Comment: По моему обратному поиску я натыкаюсь на первое максимальное число. из Вашего примера это будет 13. Потом следующим по величине будет 11. А к 2 цикл не пойдет перебирать, так как после нахождения нужных чисел он должен был вывести результат и завершиться. Но таки, действительно есть резон не экономить на время работы кода, а запустить проверку на весь диапазон.

Comment: для себя я бы делал по такому алгоритму:
- заполним массив числами 0-99999
- обнулил решетом все, кроме простых
- далее используя 2 цикла перебрал их произведения и проверил на палиндром for (int i = 99999; i>1000; i--), for(j=99999; j>=i; j--). далее если в массиве простых чисел есть числа i и j, то проверяю их произведение на палиндром (если ок, то сохраняю все три значения в временые переменые при условии что ранее найденный палиндром не был больше текущего). после циклов возвращаю результат с временных переменых. как-то так

Comment: заливать в масив я тоже хотел изначально, но остановило то что это 90000 чисел. Потому избрал метод перебора и перемножения налету. Относительно вопроса почему второй цикл идет от меньшего к большему. Когда беру какое то число, то его нужно поделить на все цифры диапазона от 2 до квадратного корня этого числа. у меня цикл завершается при первом же делении без остатка. так как шанс того что деление без остатка будет на малых числах, потому и начал с малых - чтобы уменьшить количество итераций.

Comment: В диапазоне от 1 до 100 000 количество простых чисел равно 9593
в диапазоне от 1 до 10 000 1229 числа. итоговый массив простых чисел будет иметь около 8300 чисел, что не так уж и много.

Comment: Да, но это уже после того как решето применили, но изначально то туда нужно залить 90000. я об этом. Та и чесно говоря масив  из 9593 тоже не привлекает. Хотя это было бы проще реализовать чем держать в памяти цикл и в нем запускать еще пару циклов, как я нагородил.))

Answer (score 4):

Вот правильный ответ на задачу, также встречал на собесе:
палиндром - 999949999
множитель1 - 33211
множитель2 - 30109
Реализовал алгоритм так:
Метод поиска наибольшего палиндрома (на входе список простых чисел)

```
static void palindrome(ArrayList<Integer> primeNumbers) {
    long palindrome = 0;
    long multiplier1 = 0;
    long multiplier2 = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < primeNumbers.size(); j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < primeNumbers.size(); k++) {
            long i = (long) primeNumbers.get(j) * (long) primeNumbers.get(k);
            if (palindromeCheck(i)) {
                if (i > palindrome) {
                    palindrome = i;
                    multiplier1 = primeNumbers.get(j);
                    multiplier2 = primeNumbers.get(k);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("palindrome = " + palindrome
            + "\nmultiplier1 = " + multiplier1
            + "\nmultiplier2 = " + multiplier2);
}
```

Метод поиска простых чисел (на входе максимальное и минимальное значения из проверяемого диапазона чисел):

```
static ArrayList eratosthenesPrimeNumbers(int max, int min) {
    ArrayList<Integer> primeNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean[] array = new boolean[max];

    for (int i = 2; Math.pow(i, 2) <= max; i++) {
        if (!array[i]) {
            for (int j = (int) Math.pow(i, 2); j < max; j += i) {
                array[j] = true;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = max - 1; i >= min; i--) {
        if (!array[i]) {
            primeNumbers.add(i);
        }
    }
    return primeNumbers;
}
```

Проверка на то, что найденное число является палиндромом (на входе проверяемое число):

```
static boolean palindromeCheck(long i) {
    char[] palindrome = String.valueOf(i).toCharArray();
    int fromBegin = 0;
    int fromEnd = palindrome.length - 1;
    while (fromBegin < fromEnd) {
        if (palindrome[fromBegin] == palindrome[fromEnd]) {
            fromBegin++;
            fromEnd--;
        } else return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Да и еще забыл написать, что эти методы надо вызывать :)
У меня это сделано так:

```
public class Main {
static final int MAX_MULTIPLIER = 99999;
static final int MIN_MULTIPLIER = 10000;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Integer> primeNumbers2 = new ArrayList<>(eratosthenesPrimeNumbers(MAX_MULTIPLIER, MIN_MULTIPLIER));
    palindrome(primeNumbers2);
}
```

и дальше реализация методов...

Comment: Стоило бы написать как ты его получил.

Answer (score 2):

Немного вник в алгоритм. По моему, он работает неправильно уже здесь:

```
 while (isNotPalind) {

            if (sPM <= fPM && sPM > minNum) {
                sPM = findMaxPrimeNumber(sPM - 2);
                isNotPalind = findPalindrome(fPM, sPM);

            } else if (sPM <= minNum) {
                fPM = findMaxPrimeNumber(fPM - 2);
                sPM = fPM;
            }


        }
```

Получается ты выведешь первый встречный палиндром, но нет гарантии, что он будет максимальный.

Возьмем отвлеченный от этого пример прогонки от 10 до 1 возможных произведений всех чисел.

По твоему алгоритму идем по 1-му кругу:

`10*10, 10*9 , 10*8, 10*7....` <- и сразу выводим первый попавшийся палиндром

далее второй круг:

`9*9, 9*8, 9*7...` <- или уж тут сразу выводим первый попавшийся палиндром

далее третий:

```
8*8, 8*7, 8*6...
```

И так далее...

Допустим на 1-ом круге 10*2 - это палиндром (гипотетически!)

Также допустим на 2-ом круге 9*8 - это тоже палиндром (гипотетически!)

Но твоя программа выведет 10*2 (несмотря на то что 9*8 больше чем 10*2)

То есть первое попавшееся - это не вариант.
Надеюсь автор меня понял и поправит если я не прав.

Comment: Да, конечно я Вас понял. Этот недочет уже обсуждался в коментариях к ответу @Andriy Martsinkevych. Это могло привести к ошибочному результату, но могло и к правильному. 
Но тем не менее, не это явилось ошибкой, а то что я неверно выбрал метод хранения получаемого результата умножения 2-х простых 5-тизначных чисел. Нужно было выбрать "long", я же по привычке использовал "int".