# Найти наибольший палиндром-число, которое есть произведением двух простых чисел

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.x, простые-числа

Тут есть уже похожий вопрос. Но всё-таки...
Делал т.з для одной компании. Получил отказ, "ответ неверный".
Помогите разобраться что не так. Охота ведь осознать ошибку если она есть.

вопрос: "Напишите программу, которая возвращает наибольшее число палиндром, которое является произведением двух простых пятизначных чисел, а также возвращает сами сомножители."

Мой ответ: `(9966006699, 99979, 99681)`

```
def get_palindrom():

    for i in range(99999, 90001, -1):
        if i / 2 != 0 and i / 3 != 0 and i / 5 != 0 and i / 7 != 0:
            for j in range(99999, 90001, -1):
                if j / 2 != 0 and j / 3 != 0 and j / 5 != 0 and j / 7 != 0:
                    prod = i * j
                    if str(prod) == str(prod)[::-1]:
                        return prod, i, j
    print(get_palindrom())
```

Comment: а почему именно эти ограничения выставлены? Вдруг одно больше число можно сделать, а другое меньше.

Comment: "Результат произведения двух пятизначных чисел"

число должно быть максимальным. Собственно поэтому и выставил такой диапазон. Если с нуля идти к большему очень на долго этот процесс зависает, начал с конца.
Ещё пробовал набивать список результатами н-ного количества итераций (ставил 10 и 20) и максимальный ответ был тот-же

Comment: ещё раз... откуда взялось ограничение СНИЗУ?

Comment: Всё, сорри, не тот вариант выложил. Это уже кода игрался и варианты искал...ещё раз сорри

Comment: `for i in range(99999, 90001, -1):for j in range(99999, 90001, -1):` А то, что 99999*90001 гораздо меньше 99998*99998, тебя не смущает?

Comment: 1) Данные два множителя не есть "простыми" числами;
2) Результат умножения этих двух чисел не будет палиндромом.
Будьте добры...я же вроде задание чётко указал....

Comment: У вас неправильная проверка на простоту

Comment: Что ещё смешнее 99681 делится на 3

Comment: Этот вопрос смотрели: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/706061/243186 ? Хоть и java версия но алгоритм такой же. У меня так и не хватило силы и времени (точнее желания его доделать алгоритм и оптимизировать). Может когда-то и дойду к тому чтобы доделать.

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, у вас неправильная проверка на простоту:
помимо простых чисел в диапазоне 0...10 существует еще бесконечное множество простых чисел.

Во-вторых, такого числа может просто не оказаться среди множителей из выбранного вами диапазона(90001...99999) - один из множителей может быть, например, 77813.

Answer (score 1):

Так как ограничений на время нет, то можно в лоб все произведения простых чисел с 5 цифрами перебрать:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from itertools import combinations


def ispalindrome(n):
    digits = str(n)
    return digits == digits[::-1]


def primes_upto(limit): 
    """Sieve of Eratosthenes."""
    prime = [True] * limit
    for n in range(2, limit):
        if prime[n]:
            yield n  # prime
            for composite in range(n * n, limit, n):
                prime[composite] = False


primes5digit = [p for p in primes_upto(10**5) if p > 10**4]
print(*max((p * q, p, q) for p, q in combinations(primes5digit, 2)
           if ispalindrome(p * q)))
```

Подождать десятки секунд и результат:

```
999949999 30109 33211
```

Answer (score 0):

Кажется разобрался...
В проверке на то является ли число простым поставил не тот знак...должно быть "%" вместо "/"
ну и соответственно ответ другой получился...судя по всему оно...

Comment: проверка остатка деления (% p) где p 2,3,5,7 не достаточно, чтобы гарантировать что число простое. К примеру, 99979 не является простым.

Answer (score 0):

Как Вам такой подход:

```
from sympy import sieve
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

def max_palindrome(prime_numbers):
    prime_numbers_list_unique_combinations = combinations_with_replacement(prime_numbers, 2)
    list_palindromes = ((i * j, i, j) for i, j in prime_numbers_list_unique_combinations if \
                        str(i * j) == str(i * j)[::-1])
    result = max(list_palindromes)
    return "The max palindrome with product numbers {1} and {2} is: {0}".format(result[0], \
                                                                                 result[1], \
                                                                                 result[2])

print max_palindrome((i for i in sieve.primerange(9999*3, 99999/3)))
# The max palindrome with product numbers 30109 and 33211 is: 999949999
```

requirements:

```
mpmath==1.0.0
sympy==1.1.1
```